# Using ggplot function to create plot based on cumulative data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently struggling with the data visualisation tools that R provides.
I am using the dataframe:

```
Code   Country       Date     Continent NewCases NewDeaths Recovered
1  ARG Argentina 2020-03-04 South America        1         0         0
2  ARG Argentina 2020-03-06 South America        1         0         0
3  ARG Argentina 2020-03-07 South America        6         0         0
4  ARG Argentina 2020-03-08 South America        1         1         0
5  ARG Argentina 2020-03-09 South America        3         0         0
6  ARG Argentina 2020-03-11 South America        7         0         0
  NewTests Population    GDP GDPCapita Month Week CumCases CumDeaths
1        0   44494502 637486     14400     3   10        1         0
2        0   44494502 637486     14400     3   10        2         0
3        0   44494502 637486     14400     3   10        8         0
4        0   44494502 637486     14400     3   10        9         1
5        0   44494502 637486     14400     3   10       12         1
6        0   44494502 637486     14400     3   11       19         1
  CumRecovered CumTests
1            0        0
2            0        0
3            0        0
4            0        0
5            0        0
6            0        0
```

and trying to create a line plot based on the Cumulative variables (Cases, Deaths and Recovered) using the `ggplot`function.

The code I have tried is:

```
ggplot(data = MASTER_COVID_CUMUL)+ 
#Infected cases (black)
  geom_line(aes(x = Date,
                y = CumCases),
            colour = 'black') +
#Cumulative deaths (blue)
  geom_line(aes(x = Date,
                y = CumDeaths),
            colour = 'red') +
#Cumulative recovered (green)
  geom_line(aes(x = Date,
                y = CumRecovered),
            colour = 'green')
```

Which created this complete mess

[image]

Any suggestions on making the plot actually readable, all help incredibly appreciated!

EDIT: using Log_scale_10 function

```
ggplot(data = MASTER_COVID_CUMUL)+ 
#Infected cases (black)
  geom_line(aes(x = Date,
                y = CumCases),
            colour = 'black') +
#Cumulative deaths (blue)
  geom_line(aes(x = Date,
                y = CumDeaths),
            colour = 'red') +
#Cumulative recovered (green)
  geom_line(aes(x = Date,
                y = CumRecovered),
            colour = 'green') +
  scale_y_log10()
```

Produced this result:

[image]

and the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis 
2: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis 
>
```

Still not sure on what to do? Thanks for any help

Comment: Your lines are connecting observations from the same day from different countries. I'd recommend adding `group = Country` to the aesthetic for the different lines. Also, you're plotting data which vary across many orders of magnitude. I would recommend either adding `scale_y_log10()` to the plot, or normalizing the cases per capita or per 100,000 population so that the numbers are comparable across countries.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully, could you please explain further? I'm sorry I'm very new with R

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, as per qdread's comment above:

```
ggplot(data = MASTER_COVID_CUMUL, 
       aes(x = Date, group = Country))+ 
  #Infected cases (black)
  geom_line(aes(y = CumCases),
            colour = 'black') +
  #Cumulative deaths (blue)
  geom_line(aes(y = CumDeaths),
            colour = 'red') +
  #Cumulative recovered (green)
  geom_line(aes(y = CumRecovered),
            colour = 'green') +
  scale_y_log10()
```